# HtmlUnit running getbyxpath inside getbyxpath

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

I have html like so:

```
<div id="myId">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="name">Item1</div>
        <span class="location">32143|2323</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="name">Item1</div>
        <span class="location">32143|2323</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="name">Item1</div>
        <span class="location">32143|2323</span>
    </a>
</html>
```

Using HtmlUnit for Java, I need to grab the name and location of each anchor. I tried doing a getByXPath to pickup all the anchors, then looping through them with a for and running another getByXpath to get the name in the div. However the individual items in the list are apparently Objects, so I am unable to run a second getByXPath.

I also tried running the first getByXPath using "/a/div[@class='name']" to which I loop through the results which are Objects and I cannot find the proper method for returning the contents of the divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your xpath select element, you can cast the list to the desired type:

```
List<HtmlElement> divs = (List<HtmlElement>)document.getByXPath("//a/div[@class='name']");
```

Comment: But I need only the elements under the div with id=myId, as well, I can't figure out how to get the content out of the freaking element.

Comment: You can do too `page.getElementById("myId")`and iterate over the childrens `getChildren()`. If don't understand correctly please explain fully your purpose.

Comment: For some reason your code is returning 0 results for me: http://pastebin.com/vQ8d1RGv

Comment: yes, the xpath does not target any element. The correct xpath should be `//a/div[@class='name']` or maybe better `//a[@href='#']/div[@class='name']`

Comment: If you add that extra slash in the answer I will accept it when I can